# How to stop execution after exception in ExecuteQuery

Tags: client-object-model, remote-event-receiver

I have a Remote Event Receiver attached to a list on my SP web and code that then runs on the `ItemUpdated` event:

```
var web = clientContext.Web;
var site = clientContext.Site;
var list = web.Lists.GetById(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListId);
var item = list.GetItemById(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId);
var memberGroup = web.AssociatedMemberGroup;

clientContext.Load(web);
clientContext.Load(web.AllProperties);
clientContext.Load(item);
clientContext.Load(site);
clientContext.Load(memberGroup);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

item.BreakRoleInheritance(true, true);
item.Update();
var roleAssignment = item.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal(memberGroup);
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.RemoveAll();
roleAssignment.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

But sometimes the second half of the code breaks (for example the memberGroup wasn't found) and then the strange part comes.

I get an exception at the last `clientContext.ExecuteQuery()` that says **Value cannot be null** and then it goes back to the start of the code and tries to redo it all over again. The same happens if I add a `try catch-statement` around the last part, like this;

```
try{
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
catch {
   throw;
}
```

When I try to follow the code in the debugger it just loops over my code over and over again until I actually delete the list from the web.

Does anyone know why this is and how I break out of it?

Comment: Never seen the issue, so can't give you an answer, but have you tried using the ExceptionHandlingScope? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534976(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it an `ItemUpdated` it is calling the same code again and again. In Server object model we have `this.EventFiringEnabled = false;` to prevent the event from firing again. You may have to perform some checks to avoid the update operation recurrence. Here is a somewhat similar question: [Remote Event Receiver on updated will be fired multiple time](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94425/remote-event-receiver-on-updated-will-be-fired-multiple-time/94514#94514)

Comment: This was correct, but I still have no idea how to cancel the event receiver. Now I'm doing a check for the lastmodified time and it feels like a shady and unreliable way..