# Can we disable remote event receiver from firing inside remote event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, remote-event-receiver

I am writing a remote event receiver for our online custom list, and the RER itself do some updates to the item been added/updated, where this is causing my RER to keep firing. so is there a way when i issue a `Update()` or `SystemUpdate()` inside my RER to prevent this update from firing additional RER?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of beforeProperties and afterProperties of what you wanted to update, and if there was no difference, then you can break out of the method.

```
private static bool ShouldSecretBeUpdated(
            IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> beforeProperties,
            IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> afterProperties)
        {
            // If the property doesn't exist, then the secret should  be updated
            if (!beforeProperties.ContainsKey("field") || !afterProperties.ContainsKey("field"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
           {
        //if the property exists, not do the event receiver
                return false;
           }
   
        }
using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    // When new case is added or updated, this is the method that gets triggered
                    if (properties.EventType.Equals(SPRemoteEventType.ItemUpdated))
                    {
                        var afterProperties = properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties;
                        var beforeProperties = properties.ItemEventProperties.BeforeProperties;
 
                        if (ShouldSecretBeUpdated(beforeProperties, afterProperties))
                        {
                            //do update event receiver
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

More references:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/aa995dc2-ce1f-443c-959d-dc34519d574c/remote-event-receiver-item-added-updated-disableeventfiring-provider-hosted-app-sharepoint?forum=sharepointdevelopment
- [Remote Event Receiver on updated will be fired multiple time](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94425/remote-event-receiver-on-updated-will-be-fired-multiple-time)

BR